# Барабанчик из iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать [Барабанчик из iPhone](http://www.iphones.ru/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/april.jpg), как он работает, кто знает?

Comment: Обычный селект по умолчанию в айфоне. 

Comment: не в айфоне, мне надо сверстать это на html js и css